# Why is create react app npm start deploying previous version of code?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

When running npm start to deploy my code to localhost:3000 the version displayed is a previous version of the code.

I've tried resetting my editor (Visual Studio Code) and Node.js. Tried disable cache in the network inspector of Chrome.

The browser will reload upon a save, however it will not use the correct code. It continues to 'hang' on the previous version.

Comment: have you tried using another browser?

Comment: maybe you are in a different branch, or in a previous commit.

Comment: You can also try to copy-paste the code in a new create-react-app project and run npm start. Tell us what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentially an issue with the create-react-app service worker.

Can you please look for that file, and remove it or comment it out?

Otherwise, it is possible you have an error in your code.